# Returning a string minus first and last characters to recursive function

Tags: python

I am only new to python.
I need to write a function that returns `True` if <= 1 character, `False` if the first and last characters aren't the same, and if they are the same remove the first and last characters and return the result back into the function

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len.word <= 1:
        return True
    elif word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    elif:
        return str.is_palindrome([1],len.word[-1]):          

possible_palindrome = input("Enter a word/phrase to check: ")
```

Comment: You want `len(word)` and `is_palindrome(word[1:-1])`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    elif word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_palindrome(word[1:-1])
```